# Php function fopen is not working in mac

Tags: mac, php, xampp

I am running php script in which fopen function is not working its showing error. I am using local environment.

```
$newf = fopen ($newfname, 'wb');
```

Warning: fopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xxxxxx/uploads/image.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xxxxx/xxx.php on line 9
Can you help me out how i handle this error?

Comment: Grant the appropriate permissions and make sure that (if applicable) base directory is correctly set.

Comment: @Seth i already gave the permission to the folder read and write permission and i am setting base directory like that $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/material/uploads/image.jpg".. still its giving same error

Comment: Did you give that permission to the right group/user. What are the current permissions on the folder?

Comment: yes I gave read and write permission to the user on the folder

Comment: Which user? Your user? The user that the XAMPP is run as or another user? As I mentioned, what's the actual permissions on that folder?

Comment: actual permission was only read and I gave the read & write permission.

Comment: So you set it to 644, 664 or 666? Did you check that you gave write permissions (depending on which you used) to the XAMPP user?